# Excel VBA Match Header Name on Different Workbook and Copy Column to Master Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I would like to run a macro that finds columns based on the header strings in a Source Workbook, copies the visible rows below the header, and pastes into a different Master workbook in a specified column location.

There are about 5 specific columns I need to copy data from, for example "Part Name", "Part Number", "Vendor", ect. I need to use string values because where I am pasting the values on the master workbook has different headers. "Part Number" on the source workbook might translate to "Part #" on the Master workbook.

I have tried the code below, and it works but it is very slow, and this is just for 1 column.

Any ideas how to clean up this code and make it run more smoothly and quickly?

Thanks!

I have tried calling an Optimize function that turns of screen updating, automatic calculations, ect.

```
Sub Import()

Call Optimize

Dim source As String Dim dest As String

'Clears the Table Call CleanTheTable

source = Worksheets("Set-Up").Range("B11") '<=== Source workbook based on cell value

dest = Worksheets("Set-Up").Range("B8") '<=== Destination workbook based on cell value

'------------ Header Value to Look Up -------------     

Workbooks(source).Worksheets("Source Sheet").Range("Table1[Value to Look Up]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _     Destination:=Workbooks(dest).Worksheets("INPUTS1").Range("A2")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would avoid using the copy method altogether.  It's ridiculously slow because it will copy formatting as well.  If you don't need the formatting copied, then I'd just equate the cells directly:

TargetSheet.cell.value = SourceSheet.cell.value

This is typically much faster than using the .copy method.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello thank you for the reply! This seems like a possible route to explore. How would I specify the target cells based on the column header name?